# Locating li element inside ul element

Tags: selenium, robotframework

i would like to get the count of li elements created inside ul element with a particular id. Below is the structure

```
<ul id="someid">
  <li class="someclass"></li>
  <li class="someclass"></li>
  <li class="someclass"></li>
  <li class="someclass"></li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help me locate li element with xpath.thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What difficulties have you faced?

Comment: i have tried using css and xpath to locate li element. used css=ul[@id="someid"]//li and with xpath://ul[@id="someid"]//li[class="someclass"]

Comment: Basically i would like to get the count of li elements (using Get xpath count) created within ul elements and loop through the elements to click each list element and check if the image is visible for it. Meaning within each li element i have img element again

Comment: This seem to be complex task with several possible issues. You should ask one question per issue

Comment: A CSS selector, `#someid li` is the simplest way to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following xpath

```
//ul[@id="someid"]/li[@class="someclass"]
```

If you want to filter the li elements you can give the restrictions based on attributes of the tag. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using it and i get this error. InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //ul[@id="topics_list"]/li[@class="tab"]. because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//ul[@id="topics_list"]/li[@class="tab"].' is not a valid XPath expression

Comment: @Harika , remove the dot at the end of expression

Comment: xpath expression //ul[@id="topics_list"]/li[@class="tab"]. that was a typing mistake here.

Comment: @Harika try using "//ul[@id='topics_list']/li[@class='tab']".

Comment: thanks tried it doesn't work. getting this erro. InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression "//ul[@id='topics_list']/li[@class='tab']" because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

Comment: @Harika does the webpage contain the elements you are finding? verify the xpath using firebug on firefox. If you can find the element then there might be loading issue give some timeout.

Comment: Thanks alot works...used Wait until element is visible. somehow i forget using this...

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of `<li>` elements created inside the `<ul>` element with a particular id you can use the following `xpath` :

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='someid']/li[@class='someclass']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below code to get count of `<li>` elements

```
List<WebElement> count=driver.findElements(By.Xpath(" //ul[@id="someid"]/li[@class="someclass"]"));
    count.size()
```